# I can not save the associated models (ActiveAndroid)

Tags: android, retrofit, activeandroid

I use the library [ActiveAndroid with RetroFit](http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/using-retrofit-with-activeandroid/).

if I have a simple model, it all works well. but if the model contains a different model, I do not know how all this is stored in the database

My model:

```
@Table(name="User7s")
public class User extends Model {
    @Expose
    @Column(name="name")
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @Expose
    @Column(name="sname")
    @SerializedName("sname")
    public String sname;
    @Expose
    @Column(name="age")
    @SerializedName("age")
    public int age;
}
```

my second model:

```
@Table(name="Params")
public class Params extends Model {
    @Expose
    @Column(name="heigth")
    @SerializedName("heigth")
    public String heigth;
    @Expose
    @Column(name="weight")
    @SerializedName("weight")
    public String weight;
}
```

my JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Pavel",
    "sname": "Petrashov",
    "age": 24,
    "params": {
        "heigth": 188,
        "weight": 72
    }
}
```

Then I save the user. but I want my user to contain parameters. how do I add them?

```
public void saveUser(View view) {
        RestApiStorege.me().getApiUser().getUser(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(User user, Response response) {
               user.save();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d("MyLog",error.getBody().toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

EDIT: I want my model looked like and save

```
@Table(name="User7s")
public class User extends Model {
    @Expose
    @Column(name="name")
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @Expose
    @Column(name="sname")
    @SerializedName("sname")
    public String sname;
    @Expose
    @Column(name="age")
    @SerializedName("age")
    public int age;
    @Expose
    @Column(name="params")
    @SerializedName("params")
    public Params params;

    public User() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "my user to contain parameters" ?

Comment: why you dont use foreign key?this guide show how you do it [site](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ActiveAndroid-Guide)

Comment: I am weak in databases. can give an example code how to solve my problem, and I think understand how things work in the future

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is something like this:

```
user.save();
```

That should work without throwing any red flags but when you try to retrieve the user object and access params you'll likely get a null object exception because params won't be set. Instead you must do something like this:

```
params.save();
user.save();
```

This saves params to the database and then when you save user you'll be able to retrieve params. The issue is that you aren't saving params. If you want to make life easier you can add a method to your User object that looks like this

```
public void CascadeSave() {
    this.params.save();
    this.save();
}
```

This will take care of everything for you, you just have to remember to not use `.save()` on the user object anymore.

Comment: That did it for me, this should be implemented by the library :(